# how to stop duplicate entries to be inserted while updating in database in laravel 8?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am facing an issue while updating in an array in laravel.

so the thing is, I have many to many relationship between `template_id` and `option_id`. Here is the migration file of `product_template_options`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('product_template_options', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = "InnoDB";
        
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('template_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('option_id');
        $table->boolean('is_active')->default('1');

        $table->foreign('template_id')->references('id')->on('product_templates');
        $table->foreign('option_id')->references('id')->on('product_options');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
    
}
```

Now main thing is I am able to insert new `option_id` related to `template_id`.

When updating it, means removing some previous `option_id` and adding some new `option_id` to it. When removing some previous `option_id`, I am able to delete it from the database. While inserting new I am able to insert new also, but main thing is I am getting some duplicate entries also, like this  in [phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YY5Pd.jpg),
I am trying to insert via postman [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmiTm.jpg),
here you can see I am not removing `option_id = 1`, but removed some previous `option_id = like [2,3]`. However, I am getting duplicate entry of `option_id = 1`.

How do I stop it from being inserted in database while updating array?
Here is the code for updating options:

```
   /**
 * update Options into Template 
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\Models\ProductTemplateOption  $ProductTemplateOption
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 * @param  int $Template_id 
 * 
 */
public function UpdateOptions(Request $request,$Template_id,ProductTemplateOption $ProductTemplateOption)
{
    
    $input = $request->all();
    
    // dd($input);
    $validator = Validator::make($input, [
        'option_id.*' => 'required | unique : product_template_options,option_id,'.$Template_id,
    ]);    
    
    // dd($options);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return response()->json([
            "message" => "validation failed",
        ]);
    }

    $Option_id = $request->input('option_id');
    // dd($Option_id);
    
    $FetchOptions = ProductTemplateOption::where('template_id',$Template_id)->pluck('option_id')->toArray();
    // dd($FetchOptions);
    
    $DifferencedOption = array_diff($FetchOptions,$Option_id);
    // dd($DifferencedOption);

    $RequestedOptions = array_diff($Option_id,$FetchOptions);
    // dd($RequestedOptions);

    if (count($DifferencedOption) > 0) {
        ProductTemplateOption::whereNotIn('option_id',$Option_id)->where('template_id', $Template_id)->delete();
    }

    if (count($Option_id) > 0) {
        foreach ($request->option_id as $Option_id => $options){
           $HaveOptions =  ProductTemplateOption::where('template_id',$Template_id)->where('option_id','=',$options)->exists();
            if ($HaveOptions === null) {
                $ProductTemplateOption = new ProductTemplateOption;   
                $ProductTemplateOption->template_id = $Template_id; 
                $ProductTemplateOption->option_id = $options;
                $ProductTemplateOption->is_active = 1;
                $ProductTemplateOption->save();
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
          }
    }
    

}
```

Could anyone help how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a composite `unique` key to your table migration to guard against duplicates:

```
$table->unique(['template_id', 'option_id'], 'template_option_unique_key');
```

You might also want to add some validation to check for `unique`-ness before you even hit the database:

```
'template_id' => 'required|unique:product_template_options, template_id, NULL, NULL, option_id, ' . $request['option_id'],
'option_id.*' => 'required|unique:product_template_options, option_id, NULL, NULL, template_id, ' . $request['template_id'],
```

The idea is to check that a given `template_id` and `option_id` is `unique`. The `option_id.*` checks each of the elements in the `option_id` array.

Rather than deleting records when you're updating, why not make use of the [`sync`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#syncing-associations) method on a `BelongsToMany` relationship?

```
$model->relationship()->sync($option_ids);
```

Comment: hey there, could you explain me the uniqueness section , as one option_id  can be given to many template_id , then how it will be unique

Comment: or may be I am not able to understand your code or explanation

Comment: @happysoul I made an adjustment to the example.